# Avoid Full Table Scan - Extract First Row Only

Tags: oracle11g, query-optimization, full-table-scan

I am trying to write a query that only extract the first (random) row when condition is met.

```
-- Create table
create table TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLE
(
  institution_id               NUMBER(5) not null,
  id                           NUMBER(10) not null,
  partitionkey                 NUMBER(10) default 0 not null,
  cardid                       NUMBER(10),
  accountid                    NUMBER(10),
  batchid                      NUMBER(10) not null,
  amt_bill                     NUMBER(16,3),
  load_date                    DATE not null,
  trxn_date                    DATE not null,
  single_msg_flag              NUMBER(5),
  authaccounttype              VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  originator                   VARCHAR2(50),
  amount                       NUMBER(16,3) default 0.000 not null,
  embeddedfee                  NUMBER(16,3) default 0.000 not null,,
  valuedate                    DATE,
  startofinterest              DATE,
  minduevaluedate              DATE,
  postdate                     DATE,
  posttimestamp                DATE,
  Status                       CHAR(4 BYTE) default 'NEW' not null,
)
partition by list (PARTITIONKEY)
(
  partition 0002913151 values (1234567)
    tablespace LIVE
    pctfree 10
    initrans 16
    maxtrans 255
    storage
    (
      initial 8M
      next 1M
      minextents 1
      maxextents unlimited
    )
);

-- Create/Recreate indexes 
create index TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLEI01 on TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLE (ACCOUNTID)
  local;
create index TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLEI02 on TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLE (LOAD_DATE)
  local;
create index TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLEI03 on TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLE (BATCHID)
  local;
create index TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLEI04 on TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLE (POSTDATE)
  local;
create index TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLEI05 on TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLE (POSTTIMESTAMP)
  local;
create index TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLEI06 on TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLE (STATUS, PARTITIONKEY)
  local;
create index TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLEI07 on TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLE (CARDID, TRXN_DATE)
  local;
create unique index TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLEUI01 on TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLE (ID, PARTITIONKEY)
  local;
-- Create/Recreate primary, unique and foreign key constraints 
alter table TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLE
  add constraint TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLEPK primary key (ID, PARTITIONKEY);

--QUERY
Select * From (
Select t.AccountId From Transactions_sample t Group by t.Accountid Having Count(t.AccountId) > 10 order by dbms_random.random)
Where Rownum = 1
```

The problem With this Query is full table scan. I want to achieve the same results without having to fully Access the table. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Surely you have to look at every row to get the count, before you can reduce to a single random row? Are you expecting a full index scan (of TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLEI01) rather than a full table scan? If your stats are up to date the nullability of that column might prevent it - since it may have to count values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it down to a full index scan, using `TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLEI01`, if you add a filter for `where AccountId is not null`. But only if you don't want to count null values, of course.

The column is nullable, but the index doesn't contain null values. To include the count of nulls it has to do a full table scan because it cannot get that count from the index. If you have that filter the optimizer knows all the account ID values must be in the index, so it only has to refer to that, not the table itself.

```
explain plan for
Select * From (
Select t.AccountId From Transactions_sample t where AccountId is not null Group by t.Accountid Having Count(t.AccountId) > 10 order by dbms_random.random)
Where Rownum = 1;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 381125580                                                                                                                                                                              

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                   
| Id  | Operation                  | Name                   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |                                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                   
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |                        |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                   
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY             |                        |       |       |            |          |       |       |                                                                                   
|   2 |   VIEW                     |                        |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                   
|*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY   |                        |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                   
|*  4 |     FILTER                 |                        |       |       |            |          |       |       |                                                                                   
|   5 |      SORT GROUP BY NOSORT  |                        |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                   
|   6 |       PARTITION LIST SINGLE|                        |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     1 |                                                                                   
|*  7 |        INDEX FULL SCAN     | TRANSACTIONS_SAMPLEI01 |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     1 |                                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                   

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                                                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                     

   1 - filter(ROWNUM=1)                                                                                                                                                                                 
   3 - filter(ROWNUM=1)                                                                                                                                                                                 
   4 - filter(COUNT("T"."ACCOUNTID")>10)                                                                                                                                                                
   7 - filter("ACCOUNTID" IS NOT NULL)                                                                                                                                                                  

Note                                                                                                                                                                                                    
-----                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

Alternatively, if the column can be made not-nullable then the filter wouldn't be required.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I have one additional follow up question. Say that I was to join the transaction table With a secondary table (Accounts).
Table Account holds 3 columns ID,Status and Balance. Column ID(unique) and Status is nullable and indexed. How to avoid full table scan of account table?

Select * From (
Select t.AccountId From Transactions_sample t, accounts a 
Where t.accountid is not null and t.accountid=a.id and a.status ='OPEN' Group by t.Accountid Having Count(t.AccountId) > 10 order by dbms_random.random)
Where Rownum = 1

Comment: @user3651825 - unless `status` is indexed you can't really; well, you could have an index look-up based on the `t.accountid` as a join condition, but you are looking at every row in `t` anyway so that would be slower than a FTS. And unless you have a small proportion of open accounts (like, 5%, which seems unlikely) it probably wouldn't be any faster to filter on that any earlier anyway.

Comment: @user3651825 - and it depends whether it would actually make a difference to your timings. A FTS is sometimes the best choice, and it looks like it is here. You *could* get your subset of all account IDs that have 10+ rows; join that to your `account` table; filter on status; and apply the order-by and rownum to *that* reduced result set. But again the proportion of accounts that would match might make a FTS the right choice anyway. It feels like you're heading into premature-optimisiation territory now - fixing a problem you think you might have, but which isn't real. Hard to tell.

Comment: Status is indexed. The query above still runs full table scan rather than index scan

Comment: But what proportion of account records have status open? If more than a small percentage match a full scan is still usually faster. You'd have to rewrite to have it try to use that index, but I'm really not sure it would improve it.

Comment: A large proportion is open. I will follow your suggestions. Thanks fot pointing out